# Returning an unordered_map inside an unordered_map from a function

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am trying to return a copy of an unordered_map from inside an unordered_map.

The following code illustrates my problem more clearly:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, int> Foo;
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo> FooContainer;    

...

FooContainer bar;
// etc

...

Foo GetSubmap(std::string name)
{
    // ???
}
```

I am not sure how I would go about doing this, as unordered_map.find(foo) returns an iterator for the container.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `return bar[name]` ?

Comment: 1) Check if the iterator isn't the end iterator. 2) Return the dereferenced iterator.

Comment: @NedStark yes. No operand matches.

Comment: @DyP This looks hopeful, shall try it now!

Comment: Depending on your requirements you could return a (`const`) reference and throw an exception if there is no element matching `name`.

Comment: @IInspectable I think a const reference would be a good idea, and as for the exception, that's exactly what I planned to do :)

Comment: Oh, it's a pair. So the element is in the member `second` of the pair returned from dereferencing an iterator.

Comment: `return bar[name];` works for me. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75cdfbd01b05c218)

Comment: @DyP tried again without const on my method and it works, thank you!

Comment: "without const on my method" There's no `const` in your question ;) `unordered_map<..>::operator[]` is a mutating function, so you cannot call it from a const member function. Better use `find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return empty map if no element found you can do as simply as this:

```
Foo GetSubmap(std::string name)
{
    FooContainer::const_iterator f = bar.find( name );
    return f != bar.end() ? f->second : Foo();
}
```

Or you may throw exception in case no element found. You can also use `bar[name]`, but you should know that it has side effect - empty Foo will be inserted into `bar` each time you lookup for non existing element.

Comment: why second and not first?

Comment: @OMGtechy because first is the key, second is the value. `f->first` will be equal to `name` if f != bar.end().

Comment: ah, thank you for that. I haven't worked with maps or unordered maps much at all.

Comment: @OMGtechy note that unlike `bar[name]` this code will work with const FooContainer

Comment: This worked great thanks! Just so you know, I chose to throw an exception if it doesn't exist.

Comment: In case of throwing exception you may want to return `const Foo &`